# Для чего используется тип возвращаемого значения?

Tags: java, return

Не могли бы вы объяснить, зачем нужен тип возвращаемого значения **return** в Java. Ну, то есть, для чего?

Comment: В сети огромное колличество объяснений по этой теме. Уже жевано-разжевано-пережовано. Например [вот](http://pr0java.blogspot.com/2015/05/return.html).

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F

Answer (score 2):

Если просто, то return нужен для возвращения какого-то результата после выполнения метода.

После оператора return указывается возвращаемое значение, которое является результатом метода. Это может быть литеральное значение, значение переменной или какого-то сложного выражения. 
Например:

```
public class Program{

    public static void main (String args[]){

        int x = sum(1, 2, 3);
        int y = sum(1, 4, 9);
        System.out.println(x);  // 6
        System.out.println(y);  // 14
    }
    static int sum(int a, int b, int c){

        return a + b + c;
    }
}
```

В методе в качестве типа возвращаемого значения вместо void используется любой другой тип. В данном случае метод sum возвращает значение типа int, поэтому этот тип указывается перед названием метода. Причем если в качестве возвращаемого типа для метода определен любой другой, отличный от void, то метод обязательно должен использовать оператор return для возвращения значения.

При этом возвращаемое значение всегда должно иметь тот же тип, что значится в определении функции. И если функция возвращает значение типа int, то после оператора return стоит целочисленное значение, которое является объектом типа int. Как в данном случае это сумма значений параметров метода.